# Swift - Returning Date Difference Returns 0?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I have the following Swift function which will check whether a requested date of leave falls before or after a companies leave application window - in this instance the fictional company opens it's leave window 3 months ahead of time meaning I'm unable to book leave any more than 3 months in the future.

This particular function takes the requested date as its single parameter which is of type String. It then:

- gets the current date (A)
- formats the date supplied in the parameter (B)
- gets the date 3 months prior to the requested date (C)
- finally we check if (C) is greater than (B) which if true returns a String alerting the user to the fact they have X days until the leave window opens.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation 

func requestLeave(requestedDate: String) -> String {
    
    // GET CURRENT DATE (A)
    let currentDate = Date()
    print("Current Date: \(currentDate.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))")
    
    // GET REQUESTED DATE (B)
    // STRING TO DATE 
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    guard let requestedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: requestedDate) else { 
        return ("Return some form of error String") 
    }
    
    print("You have requested leave on \(requestedDate.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))")
    
    // GET APPLICATION WINDOW OPEN DATE (C)
    // (LEAVE WINDOW OPENS - 3 MONTHS (7890000))
    let windowOpenDate = requestedDate - 7890000 
    print("Applications for leave opens on \(windowOpenDate.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))")
    
    
    
    if windowOpenDate > currentDate {
        let daysBetween = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: currentDate, to: windowOpenDate)
        
        return ("Your leave window opens in \(daysBetween.day ?? 9999) days")
    }
    
    let daysBetween = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: windowOpenDate, to: currentDate)
    return ("Your leave window opened \(daysBetween.day ?? 9999) days ago!")
}

let request = requestLeave(requestedDate: "10-08-2023")
print(request)
```

This'll print:

```
Current Date: 27 April 2023
You have requested leave on 10 August 2023
Applications for leave opens on 10 May 2023
Your leave window opens in 12 days
```

So far so good. The issue that I'm experiencing is when I run with the function with the following dates they each return that the leave window opens in 0 days:

```
let request = requestLeave(requestedDate: "28-07-2023") // ... Your leave window opens in 0 days
let request = requestLeave(requestedDate: "29-07-2023") // ... Your leave window opens in 0 days
```

These are the only 2 dates which return 0. Is this something to do with the times? Am I formatting the dates incorrectly? Can I strip the dates generated in A, B and C to equate just the dates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's clear from your code that you know about the Calendar and DateComponents classes so why do you do something like `let windowOpenDate = requestedDate - 7890000` in your code? Use the knowledge you have instead.

Comment: In my mind the main issue is that the number of days between `Date` instances is independent of the calendar being used to express those dates, and so one shouldn't need to involve a calendar.  It would be different if the question were about the number of months between them, because the definition of a month does depend on the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `Calendar` over-complicates it. Since the number of days between two `Date` instances is independent of the calendar, you can calculate it directly:

```swift
func wholeDaysBetween(earlierDate: Date, laterDate: Date) -> Int
{
    precondition(earlierDate <= laterDate)
    
    // Remove time of day portion of the dates
    let secondsPerDay: TimeInterval = 24 * 60 * 60
    let earlierEpochDays = (earlierDate.timeIntervalSince1970 / secondsPerDay)
        .rounded(.down)
    let laterEpochDays = (laterDate.timeIntervalSince1970 / secondsPerDay)
        .rounded(.down)
    
    let dateDiff = laterEpochDays - earlierEpochDays
    return Int(dateDiff)
}
```

Although I doubt that `requestLeave` is likely to be a performance bottleneck, calculating the time intervals directly like this has the incidental benefit of being faster than going through `Calendar`.

Of course, you can put that in an extension on `Date` if you prefer.  In any case, that function strips away the time of day portion of the dates, because even if it's 10pm, if the window opens tomorrow, assuming finer granularity isn't needed for some reason, we humans still think in terms of that being 1 day from now.

Your `requestLeave` function looks like this when using `wholeDaysBetween`:

```swift
func requestLeave(requestedDate: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    // GET CURRENT DATE (A)
    let currentDate = Date()
    print("Current Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate))")

    // GET REQUESTED DATE (B)
    // STRING TO DATE
    guard let requestedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: requestedDate) else {
        return ("Return some form of error String")
    }
    
    print("You have requested leave on \(dateFormatter.string(from: requestedDate))")

    // GET APPLICATION WINDOW OPEN DATE (C)
    // (LEAVE WINDOW OPENS - 3 MONTHS (7890000))
    let windowOpenDate = requestedDate - 7890000
    print("Applications for leave opens on \(dateFormatter.string(from: windowOpenDate))")

    if windowOpenDate > currentDate
    {
        let daysBetween = wholeDaysBetween(earlierDate: currentDate, laterDate: windowOpenDate)
        return ("Your leave window opens in \(daysBetween) days")
    }
    
    let daysBetween = wholeDaysBetween(earlierDate: windowOpenDate, laterDate: currentDate)
    return ("Your leave window opened \(daysBetween) days ago!")
}
```

**Note:** I got errors on `print` statements from expressions like `someDate.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted)` , so I replaced them with `dateFormatter.stringFrom(someDate)!`, which means that later when I show output, the date format won't match yours.

Since I'm writing this on April 27, 2023, the 2nd of your examples, the one for `28-07-2023`, correctly returns 0, because window open date is today.

So if I drive it with this code:

```swift
for requestDate in ["10-08-2023", "28-07-2023", "29-07-2023"]
{
    let request = requestLeave(requestedDate: requestDate)
    print("\(request)\n")
}
```

it gives this output:

```
Current Date: 27-04-2023
You have requested leave on 10-08-2023
Applications for leave opens on 10-05-2023
Your leave window opens in 13 days

Current Date: 27-04-2023
You have requested leave on 28-07-2023
Applications for leave opens on 27-04-2023
Your leave window opens in 0 days

Current Date: 27-04-2023
You have requested leave on 29-07-2023
Applications for leave opens on 28-04-2023
Your leave window opens in 1 days
```

See the earlier note about why the date formats don't match your output.

As an aside, since `requestLeave` depends on the current date, that will make writing reliable tests difficult. So for testing purposes, you might consider passing in `currentDate` as a parameter with a default value:

```swift
func requestLeave(requestedDate: String, currentDate: Date = Date()) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    // GET CURRENT DATE (A) - already done
    print("Current Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate))")

    // GET REQUESTED DATE (B)
    // STRING TO DATE
    guard let requestedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: requestedDate) else {
        return ("Return some form of error String")
    }
    
    print("You have requested leave on \(dateFormatter.string(from: requestedDate))")

    // GET APPLICATION WINDOW OPEN DATE (C)
    // (LEAVE WINDOW OPENS - 3 MONTHS (7890000))
    let windowOpenDate = requestedDate - 7890000
    print("Applications for leave opens on \(dateFormatter.string(from: windowOpenDate))")

    if windowOpenDate > currentDate
    {
        let daysBetween = wholeDaysBetween(earlierDate: currentDate, laterDate: windowOpenDate)
        return ("Your leave window opens in \(daysBetween) days")
    }
    
    let daysBetween = wholeDaysBetween(earlierDate: windowOpenDate, laterDate: currentDate)
    return ("Your leave window opened \(daysBetween) days ago!")
}
```

That allows existing usage code to remain untouched, while allowing you to write reliable tests where you can set the "current" date explicitly.  For example:

```swift
func test_requestLeave_return_0_days_when_open_date_is_today()
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    let today = dateFormatter.date(from: "27-04-2023")!
    
    let request = requestLeave(requestedDate: "28-07-2023", currentDate: today)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(request, "Your leave window opens in 0 days")
}
```